# Matlab & Simulink - Load a specific .mat in a Simulink simulator

Tags: matlab, simulink, mat

I have a set of .mat files, they all represent forces on an object depending on its attitude. I'd like to load them in a Simulink simulator, but one at a time, by specifying the name of the right one.

I tried in a Matlab function but it doesn't seem to be working, as if the function "load" cannot be used through Simulink.

If anyone has an idea I'd be grateful!

Comment: Use an extrinsic function from MATLAB Function block and call load from that function.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into issues with scope and not loading the .mat files into the correct workspace.  By default Simulink uses the Base workspace to find variables.  Make sure that the function is returning and setting the correct variables here, usually it's easier to use a script to accomplish this.

This does mean that you will be utilizing the base workspace, which might not be desirable.  If you want to keep the data encapsulated you can generate a [masked subsystem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/block-masks.html) and load the parameters from within the initialization script of the mask.  This will define variables which are accessible to any block inside the masked subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: 
https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html

I'll quote the relevant stuff here:

> -Use only when generating MEX or code for Simulink® simulation.
>
> -To load compile-time constants, use coder.load.
>
> -Does not support use of the function without assignment to a structure or array. For example, use S = load(filename), not
>   load(filename).
>
> -The output S must be the name of a structure or array without any subscripting. For example, S(i) = load('myFile.mat') is not allowed.
>
> -Arguments to load must be compile-time constant character vectors.
>
> -Does not support loading objects.
>
> -If the MAT-file contains unsupported constructs, use load(filename,variables) to load only the supported constructs.
>
> -You cannot use save in a function intended for code generation. The code generator does not support the save function. Furthermore, you
>   cannot use coder.extrinsic with save. Prior to generating code, you
>   can use save to save the workspace data to a MAT-file.
>
> -You must use coder.varsize to explicitly declare variable-size data loaded using the load function.